# Laravel 10 and Livewire V3- syntax error, unexpected identifier "Name", expecting ")" on variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I keep getting a `syntax error, unexpected identifier "Name", expecting ")"` error when trying to access my model's `create` route.  The syntax is correct and all other routes and views work with the same variables. I've commented out all the `__()` Blade functions for lang and commented out the error blocks and the view works. If all the other views for this model acted the same, then it would make sense, but the fact I'm getting this error for only this view is weird. I just upgraded my project to Laravel 10, from 9, and Livewire 3 from 2.

**create.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Fcrop;

use App\Models\Farm;
use App\Models\Fcrop;
use Livewire\Component;

class Create extends Component
{
    public $farm, $name, $type, $area;

    public function mount(Farm $farm)
    {
        $this->farm = $farm;
    }

    protected $messages = [
        'name' => 'Name is required.'
    ];

    public function createCropType()
    {
        //dd($this->farm->id);
        $this->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:5',
            'area' => 'integer'
        ]);

        Fcrop::create([
            'farm_id' => $this->farm->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'type' => $this->type,
            'area' => $this->area,
        ]);


        return redirect()->route('farm.edit', $this->farm->id);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.fcrop.create');
    }
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
...
<form wire:submit="createCropType" method="POST" class="space-y-8 divide-y divide-gray-200">
    <div class="space-y-8 sm:space-y-5">
        <div class="pt-8 space-y-6 sm:pt-10 sm:space-y-5">
            <div class="space-y-6 sm:space-y-5">
                <div class="sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4 sm:items-start">
                    <label for="name" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                        {{ __('Name') }}
                    </label>
                    <div class="mt-1 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                        <input wire:model.live="name" type="text" name="name" id="name">
                        @error('name')<span
                            class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
...
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Is this just your IDE detecting phantom issues? Does your code actually work, or are you getting the Laravel error screen?

Comment: I get the Laravel error screen

Comment: Hmm interesting... `__()` (`__()` being an alias for `trans()` for translations) can accept a string as its argument, as can `@error()`. I unfortunately have no experience with `livewire`, so it might be something I personally haven't seen before, sorry.

Comment: What happens if you assign this lang to variables? `@php $la_name = __('Name') @endphp@` then `{{$la_name}}` ?

Comment: extending what @TimLewis said, this might be a livewire concern. Did you try to use the same translation in a basic blade file that was returned by a controller on a dummy route? Or are you missing the language package.

Answer (score 0):

You missed double quoute at end of class line above

```
<label for="name" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
{{ __('Name') }}
</label>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. I was removing classes to shorten the code I posted and accidentally deleted the quotes--I updated the question to include the quotes.